# Loop through values of a column Oracle

Tags: oracle, loops

I have a very basict PL/SQL question.

How do I loop through values of a certain table column and update them?

Do i do this in a loop?

Comment: What kind of values do you need to update? Is there no way for an update statement to work?

Comment: i need to loop through them so i can set it a value i'll recieve from a complicated query;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is usually no need to loop through a table. All you do is to execute an update statement of the kind

```
 UPDATE mytable
 SET    myfield = 'new value'
 WHERE  somecondition;
```

But you could also define a cursor for update. Google for "oracle cursor loop update current". One example is this http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/current_of.php

Here is my own example:

```
create table my_example(id number, somefield varchar2(80));
insert into my_example values (1, 'test 1');
insert into my_example values (2, 'test 2');
insert into my_example values (3, 'test 3');
set linesize 100
select * from my_example;

set serveroutput on
declare
  l_somefield varchar2(80);
  cursor c is select somefield from my_example for update of somefield; 
begin
  open c;
  loop
    fetch c into l_somefield;
    exit when c%notfound;
    update my_example
    set somefield = l_somefield || ' some more text'
    where current of c;
  end loop;
  close c;
end;

select * from my_example;
drop table my_example;
```

Output

```
Table created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
1 row created.

        ID SOMEFIELD                                                                       
---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 test 1                                                                          
         2 test 2                                                                          
         3 test 3                                                                          

3 rows selected.
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

        ID SOMEFIELD                                                                       
---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 test 1 some more text                                                           
         2 test 2 some more text                                                           
         3 test 3 some more text                                                           

3 rows selected.
Table dropped.
```